# Double list when assigning axios data to useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, mapping

I am attempting to import data from the backend but one of my variable names is off due to naming convention.  If I use `setEvents(results.data.events)` I get everything except for the one field.  However, when I try to loop through it to assign it manually it gives me a double list that typescript is not letting me select my data from.  Can someone point out how this is supposed to be done?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

type eventType = {
    id: number,
    slug: string,
    name: string,
    date: string,
    eventLevel: string,
    notes: string
}

export const Events = () => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState<[ 
        eventType
    ]>([{
        id: 999,
        slug: '',
        name: '',
        date: '',
        eventLevel: '',
        notes: ''          
    }]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get('event/', {withCredentials: true})

            setEvents(result.data.events.map((value: any, key: number) => [{
                id: key,
                slug: value.slug,
                name: value.name,
                date: value.date,
                eventLevel: value.event_level,
                notes: value.note
                }]))  // I think my issue is here but I break it if I remove the []
        }
        getData()
    }, []);

    return(
       {Object.entries(events).map(([key, value]) => (
            <div key={key} className='container'>
                <a href={'/journal/events/' + value.slug}>
                    <h2>{value.name}</h2>
                    <p><b>Date: </b>{ value.date}</p>
                    <p><b>Event Type: </b>{value.eventLevel}</p>
                    <p><b>Notes:</b></p>
                    <p>{value.notes}</p>
                </a>
                <p>key:  {key}</p>
                <p>value:  {JSON.stringify(value)}</p>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The reason you are getting a double array is because you are inserting each event into an array inside your map function, which itself returns an array. What breaks when you remove the extra array creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that this would fix it:

```
setEvents(result.data.events.map((value: any, key: number) => {
 return {
    id: key,
    slug: value.slug,
    name: value.name,
    date: value.date,
    eventLevel: value.event_level,
    notes: value.note
  }
 })
)
```